# BlackBerry - final step of build process

Tags: blackberry, build, build-process

What is the right way to get the final .jad & .cod files ready for distribution?

Currently I use a very poor, manual approach:

1. Package project & sign
2. Open explorer, navigate to the deliverables folder
3. Rename .cod files to .zip & extract them
4. Manually add the correct .cod files to the correct .jad file

This is wrong, but it works. What is the right way to do this? thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider [JadTool](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#jadtool) from [BlackBerry Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net)